# ARC issue - cannot pass method to delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Here's my scenario. I have a class A. Inside its implementation I create object of type B and set B's delegate to self (So `B.delegate = self` somewhere inside class A's implementation).

And class A has an instance method `- (void)printThis;`

Now inside B's implementation, when I try to do `[delegate printThis];`, it gives me this error:
"No known instance method for selector printThis"

Of course this is when I have enabled ARC. The above delegation pattern used to work fine in iOS 4.x without the ARC. And it still does when I switch OFF ARC. What has ARC got to do with passing messages to delegates?

Skeleton code:

A.h

```
@class B;

@interface A: blah blah
{
    B objB;
}

-(void) printThis;
```

A.m

```
objB = [[B alloc] init];
objB.delegate = self;

- (void)printThis {
    //doSomething
}
```

B.h

```
@interface B: blah blah
{
    //id delegate; //used to be there, now I just property & synthesize
}

@property (nonatomic,weak) id delegate;
```

B.m

```
@synthesize delegate;

[delegate printThis]; //error with ARC ON, works with OFF
```

IMPORTANT EDIT:

And mind you this happens for a method here and there. For instance I have a few other methods in A like printThat etc etc which work without errors. I'm clueless as to what is happening!

Comment: Just curious, do you still have the issue with ARC on if you go through the getter for `delegate` instead of accessing the ivar directly? Either way, going with the protocol is the better design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define `-printThis` in a protocol and make A implement this protocol. You also need to mark the delegate as conforming to this delegate.

i.e.:

```
@protocol Printer <NSObject>

- (void)printThis;

@end

@interface A : NSObject <Printer>
//...
@end

@interface B : //...

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<Printer> delegate;

@end
```

ARC needs to know about the interface for method calls in order to properly manage the memory correctly. If there isn't a definition then it'll complain.

Comment: My question is how is this related to enabling ARC? It works pretty darn well with ARC OFF on both iOS 4.x as well as 5.0

Comment: As for it used to work, well that was a compiler error: fix all compiler errors and warnings.

Comment: Ok wait. I do have a method declaration in the interface A : - (void) printThis;

Comment: Post your interfaces (the relevant bits)

Comment: For some reason your solution gives me the same result. No luck.

Comment: I've updated my answer, mark the delegate as `id<Protocol>` rather than just `id`.

Comment: Yup protocols worked finally. But I would love a theoretical explanation. Is it a LLVM 3.0 compiler specific thing that this is popping up on Xcode 4.2+iOS 5.0 under ARC? What has this even got to do with ARC? It still works the way it was without ARC. And what puzzles me further is certain other delegate messages work without issues even under ARC and some need protocols like this. ALL ONLY UNDER ARC in iOS 5. This is all so messed up!